# Transform query results into different format

Tags: java, pivot, spring-jdbc

my query returns result rows into list of maps like

```
ABC  year value
------------------
A+   2016 8526.00
A+   2017 10179.34
A+   2018 13351.16
A+   2014 4022.50
A+   2015 5711.01
A    2016 1052.85
A    2017 1343.61
A    2018 1546.45
A    2014 879.00
A    2015 992.95
B    2018 502.68
B    2014 561.59
B    2015 653.96
B    2016 505.70
B    2017 502.68
C    2016 300.74
C    2017 300.74
C    2018 300.74
C    2014 181.91
C    2015 300.74
C-   2016 99.95
C-   2017 99.95
C-   2015 29.99
C-   2018 99.95
C-   2014 40.76
```

How can I transform it to a format like -

```
ABC       2014       2015       2016       2017       2018
----------------------------------------------------------
A+        Val        Val        Val        Val        Val
A         Val        Val        Val        Val        Val
B         Val        Val        Val        Val        Val
C         Val        Val        Val        Val        Val
C-        Val        Val        Val        Val        Val
```

How can I do it using List and Map operations in Java?

I'm getting query results using SPRING JDBC like - 
rowList = getJDBCTemplate().queryForList(sql);'

Can anyone assist me with this [reference](https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-collectors-groupingby-and-mapping-example/)?

Comment: What `List` do you get by `queryForList(sql)`? Is it a `List<String>` or anything else?

Comment: List of Maps. Like `List<Map<String, Object>>`

Comment: OK... and the `Object` will have `year` and `value`from your example output?

Comment: @deHaar yes it is String will contain column and Object will contain value part

Comment: Does the `String` contain the `A, A+...` and does the `Object` have `getYear()` and `getValue()` methods?

Comment: @deHaar I updated the expected format. You shoub be able to get idea

Comment: You can do that in Java or in SQL, I can't tell you which way should be preferred... Depends on the query, the hardware resources and your sql skills. Can you add the query to your question?

Comment: @deHaar I already got 1st format using query result. Now I want to convert it into required format with java

Comment: That means each row of the result table is a `Map` having a single entry?

Comment: @deHaar exactly,.. you get it right. I want to do it using java. Any clue?

Comment: @deHaar can you guide me with the help from this [link](https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-collectors-groupingby-and-mapping-example/)

Comment: I could, but I don't have time at the moment and this task will take some time... I would try it the classic way first, but the final solution should be using lambdas and streams.

Comment: Please update your question with some proper code, especially the SQL query you're using and the actual return type you get from JDBC. Please confirm (or deny and correct) the following assumption: you get a `List<Map<String, Object>>` where each list element represents a row while the map contains the values with the map key being the column names, i.e. do you get something like this: `[{ABC : A+, year: 2016, value: 8526.00},{ABC: A+, year: 2017, value 10179.34}, ...]` ?

Comment: @Thomas yes, you are excatly right. Can you assiste me how I can achive this? I found one [link](https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-collectors-groupingby-and-mapping-example/) but not sure how it can help me with this. I'm clueless.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't be too hard. The simplest way would be to use a `Map<String, Map<Integer, Double>>` - assuming `year` is an integer and `value` is a double. Filling the maps should be straight forward because you just need to iterate over the results, get the 3 needed values and put them into the result map - while creating nested maps if needed. Rendering the table would require iteration over the maps and thus using `TreeMap` as the implementation (along with a comparator that puts `A+` before `A`) would help.